# mediawiki extension read data of a txt file

Tags: php, mediawiki

Hi i have following Problem.

I write a Mediawiki Extension where i need some data of a txt file. But the normally used readfile(yourtxtfile.txt) doesnt work with Mediawiki....

How can i get my data out of the txt file in my Mediawiki extension.

```
 <?php

 $wgExtensionCredits['parserhook'][] = array(

 'path' => __FILE__,
 'name' => 'UniChecker',
 'description' => 'Check the all names of specific universities',
 'descriptionmsg' => 'UniChecker-desc',
 'version' => 1, 
 'author' => 'me',
 'url' => 'https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:UniChecker',

 );

 // Specify the function that will initialize the parser function.
 $wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'UniSetupFunc';

 // Allow translation of the parser function name
 $wgExtensionMessagesFiles['ExampleExtensionMagic'] = dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/UniChecker.i18n.magic.php';


 function UniSetupFunc( &$parser ) {

    // Create a function hook associating the "example" magic word with the
    // UniParsefunc() function.
    $parser->setFunctionHook( 'Uni', 'UniParsefunc' );

    // Return true so that MediaWiki continues to load extensions.
    return true;
      }

 // Render the output of the parser function.
 function UniParsefunc( $parser, $param1 = '' ) 
 {
    if(!file_exists("Uni.txt")) echo "Data not found";  

    // here i want to open my txt file
    // readfile not work


    return $txt_data;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You neeed to provide the full path e.g. `file_exists('/var/foo/bar/Uni.txt');`

Comment: Works very well forget that its starts in the mainpath :)